# bp_get_displayed_user_nav(); is not returning correct links?

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

When using:

```
bp_get_displayed_user_nav();
```

Outside of buddypress, the navigation links inside the menu it outputs are not pointing to the correct place.

**An example of where they are pointing now:**

http://www.website.com/messages

**Where they need to point:**

http://www.website.com/users/username/messages

Answer (score 0):

The `bp_get_displayed_user_nav()` function uses the `$bp` global variable. This global contains all of the variables and configuration settings that BuddyPress needs to use throughout an installation.

For `bp_get_displayed_user_nav()` to work, it must be used inside a BuddyPress installation. Using it 'outside of BuddyPress' will result in unexpected results such as those that you're seeing.

**Ref:** http://codex.buddypress.org/developer/the-bp-global/

Answer (score 0):

@henrywright's answer is mostly correct. To add some more details, this particular function -- `bp_get_displayed_user_nav` -- gets the navigation menu for the "display" user. The "displayed user" is a BuddyPress concept where it is only set if you're on a screen that is displaying one user. For example, on a specific member's profile.

If you use it elsewhere, perhaps in a blog template, it won't work correctly.